# Is String.replace any faster than String.split ... String.join in ActionScript 3?

Tags: regex, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, string

Is it any faster to use

```
myString.replace(/foo/g,"bar")
```

rather than

```
myString.split("foo").join("bar")
```

for long strings in [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) 3? Or are they just two comparable methods of achieving the same result?

Comment: why wouldn't you just use `myString.replace("foo","bar")`. depending on the quality of AS3's regex implementation this could be faster. also, it's simpler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used gSkinners [PerformaceTest](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/04/as3_performance.html) to run a quick test on this. I think the difference is minimal at best. I would say that `replace()` would be the preferred option purely because that is what you want to achieve. Using `split().join()` is not as clear in its intent.

```
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Using replace() (10000 iterations)
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
method...................................................ttl ms...avg ms
[function]                                                   57     0.01
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Using split().join() (10000 iterations)
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
method...................................................ttl ms...avg ms
[function]                                                   61     0.01
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Comment: Thanks for running the test - it seems like replace() is the way to go for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 5):

David R. quoted from the blog Dirkgently linked:

> The string.split().join() construct is
>   a leftover from AS2 days, where there
>   was no string.replace(). In AS3, it
>   makes no sense to use .split.join,
>   only people who haven’t learned the
>   new replace function would be likely
>   to use it.

Also, the time difference appears to be minimal according to that blog. So yes, replace should be a much cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.stratulat.com/blog/replace-vs-split-and-join-performance-in-actionscript-3) a nice blog post to start with. But you really should measure to know which is faster.

Comment: After reading that page it seems that replace is the way to go. Additionally it supports regex too.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've just been refactoring all my old string.split().join().split().join()... methods to use regexp and wondered if it was worth all the effort.

Comment: @Amarghosh: split() does supports regex: demonstration: try in chrome console the following commands: `i = 'alksdfjaklsdfjksaldj flskadjf òlaksdjf òlkasdjf'; i.split(/a|f/);` they will return the array: **["", "lksd", "j", "klsd", "jks", "ldj ", "lsk", "dj", " òl", "ksdj", " òlk", "sdj", ""]**