# How to print numbers in the file name?

Tags: python

I need to sort and print "numbers" contained on the file name.

I can print the entire file names in this way :

```
data_path = './processed_train/raw'
gg = [f for f in os.listdir(data_path) if 'desc' not in f]
for g in tqdm(gg):
    print(g)
```

```
data_15299.pt
data_13730.pt
data_2294.pt
...
data_15882.pt
data_16129.pt
data_2928.pt
```

But how can I print out only the numbers on the file name?

I want to print like this:

```
15299
13730
2294
...
15882
16129
2928
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of cheapest way to achieve this by:

```
data_path = './processed_train/raw'
gg = [f for f in os.listdir(data_path) if 'desc' not in f]
for g in tqdm(gg):
    print(g.split('.')[0].split('_')[1])
```

Comment: What do you mean by cheapest and how do you measure?

Comment: Using regex takes more computation but in `split()` it separate characters by find the split character. Therefore it takes less computation.

Comment: My slicing suggestion takes 0.18 seconds for 1M strings where your split() approach takes 0.35 seconds. Almost twice as fast.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Sure: https://ideone.com/Xlchaa

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. But I was comparing `split()` with `re` which is regex. also compare with your approach `split()` has pretty similar performance. See  this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642709/9465840).

Comment: Your answer says "Cheapest way to achieve this by:" there is no comparison to anything. It is an absolute statement.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to achieve this(slicing, regex, splitting, etc).

If you use Python 3.9+, you can remove the `"data_"` with `.removeprefix()` and `".pt"` with `.removesuffix()`. They are self-descriptive hence readable.

```py
print(line.strip().removeprefix("data_").removesuffix(".pt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `data_`  and remove `.pt` by replacing with nothing:

```py
print(g.replace("data_", "").replace(".pt", ""))
```

You could also use slicing:

```py
print(g[5:][:-3]) # 5 for data_ and -3 for .pt
```

If you don't know where the numbers are (i.e. `data_` and `.pt` are different), you can only keep digits:

```py
print(''.join(char for char in g if char.isdigit()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using regex.

```py
import re

# Example List
dirList = ['data_15299.pt', 'data_13730.pt', 'data_2294.pt', 'data_15882.pt', 'data_16129.pt', 'data_2928.pt']

for i in dirList:
  print(re.split('data_|.pt', i)[1])
```